# Node NPM packages are becoming so heavy and causing problems in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows, installation, npm, package

When trying to install new npm dependency packages to our existing project, the npm packages which are getting downloaded are becoming so heavy and hangsup sometimes. But where as the same package if I try to install globally, it is installing in few seconds without any heavy download.

Does NPM installations depends upon the project folder contents, is it analyzing in that way or any other problems with the existing package?

Ex: I have installed Mocha npm package as global, which just took 4-5mb. Also tried to install the same local package in another new folder. Even their it took just the same 4-5mb. Whereas when I try to install the same in the existing built project folder, it's taking more than 200mb. Not able to find what's wrong with this. Its not just with mocha, facing the same problem with all the new npm packages, all are crossing more than 100mb.

Comment: What is the command that you used to install the packages?

Comment: `npm install mocha --save --dev`

Comment: I think the problem is in `--dev`. I don't see it anywhere in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). Try removing the `--dev`.

Comment: I think what you want is `--save-dev` because mocha is a dev dependency.  So try `npm install mocha --save-dev`